# Meteor: working with async methods

Tags: meteor, async-await, meteor-methods

I am using React with Meteor. I have a method inside React component that calls Meteor.method (which is run on client as well):

```js
// index.js
loginWithGoogle() {
        console.log('1')

        Meteor.call('auth.loginWithGoogle', {}, (err, res)=>{
            console.log('5');
            if (err) {
                console.log(err) // line 16:
            } else {
                console.log('success');
                // console.log(res);
                // console.log('logged in with google callback in react yay:)')
            }

        });
    }
```

In client side Meteor I have method:

```js
// auth.js
Meteor.methods({
    async 'auth.loginWithGoogle'(){
        console.log('2')
        let err = await Meteor.loginWithGoogle()
        console.log('3');
        console.log(err)
        if (err) {
            console.log('-1')
            throw new Error(err);
        }
        console.log('4');

        // Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
        //     // options
        // }, (err) => {
        //     console.log('3')
        //     if (err) {
        //         console.log(err)
        //         throw new Meteor.Error(err)
        //     } else {
        //         console.log('4')
        //         // successful login!
        //     }
        // });
    }
});
```

Note: Meteor.loginWithGoogle is provided by accounts-google package. 
When testing I was able to navigate to google sign in page, sign in, and redirect back to my app) and logs are then printed.

Here the commented code is old approach. Notice, I have console.log calls with numbers, the numbers indicate the order in which I expect code to be executed. The old method does not work at all, console.log('5') runs earlier than (3 and 4), due to asynchronous execution. Rewriting with async/await gives this:

```js
index.js:12 1
auth.js:4 2
auth.js:6 3
auth.js:7 undefined
auth.js:12 4
index.js:14 5
index.js:16 errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 404, reason: "Method 'auth.loginWithGoogle' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method 'auth.loginWithGoogle' not found [404]", …}
```

So, from logs I can see that code is executed as i expected.
Inside auth.js:7 I have err == undefined, but inside index.js (react part) it is errorClass.

How do we deal with async code in Meteor methods?

Comment: Actually if you removed the callback from server side, it will become synchronous, written in the docs.

Comment: @AshvinSharma, but i run code on client side, since loginWithGoogle method requires client context. Or am i getting it wrong?)

Answer (score 3):

I got it. Why I was using Meteor.methods on client? I could just use javascript function like that:

```js
const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
    console.log('2')
    let err = await Meteor.loginWithGoogle()
    console.log('3');
    console.log(err)
    if (err) {
        console.log('-1')
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    console.log('4');

}
export {
    loginWithGoogle
}
```

I just use async function, it returns Promise.

Inside React I use async syntax too:

```js
async loginWithGoogle() {
        let err = await loginWithGoogle()
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            console.log('success')
        }

    }
```